# How to load controller method from reqs string like "controller#action"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I want to load the instance method of create from the reqs string(routing term) and then find its source location
This is how you would define it in the routes file

`get "route_name" => "controller#action"`

Typically, you can do this by using the following statement

`UsersController.instance_method(:create).source_location`
or even `"UsersController".constantize.instance_method(:create)`

I was wondering if there is an easy way to do this.
I know I can expand the slashes and split on the hash to load the instance method, but I am sure there's a quick way given that this is such a common thing in Rails routing

Answer (score 0):

Would this work (You would change find_path to whatever path you want to find)?

```
find_path = '/'
controller_name = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(find_path)[:controller]
controller_class = (controller_name + '_controller').classify.constantize
controller_class.instance_method(:create).source_location
```

I don't know if you prefer to parse the routes.rb file.  If not, you can get a list of all your application's routes with the following method: [Method: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#named_routes](https://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActionDispatch%2FRouting%2FRouteSet:named_routes)

Let me know if I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: So I did all of this earlier. I used the RouteInspector to get the routes and received the reqs argument. I was wondering if there is a way to directly parse the string in ruby. 
I ended up doing this
`execution_path = 'api/vi1/users_controller#create'
    controller,action = execution_path.split("#")
    controller = controller + "_controller"
    controller_class = controller.camelize.constantize
    source_code = controller_class.instance_method(action).source`

Answer (score 0):

So  I ended up using the following code:

```
execution_path= "api/v1/users_controller#action"
controller,action = execution_path.split("#")
controller = controller + "_controller"
controller_class = controller.camelize.constantize
source_code = controller_class.instance_method(action).source_location
```